# How to uniform the color and texture of a face

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to cartoonify a face using opencv.Here's the original image
[image]

Currently [I'm doing](http://www.askaswiss.com/2016/01/how-to-create-cartoon-effect-opencv-python.html)

1. Downscaling the image, applying bifilter and upscaling back to original
2. Then converting RGB of original image to grayscale and followed 
   medianblur to reduce nice
3. Apply Adaptive Threshold to create edgemask
4. Combining the image obtained from step1 with the edge mask with 
   bitmap
   Here's the output
   [image]

Then applied [non-photorealistic rendering](https://www.learnopencv.com/non-photorealistic-rendering-using-opencv-python-c/) using OpenCV. Here's the final output[image]
I want to generate face with uniform color(remove light reflection as well)without affecting the eyes, mouth. How can I achieve that either by tweaking my current code or another possible approach in opencv(python)

Comment: Very interesting. Can you explain better what you want in the last step. Do you want to color balance or do you want to reduce the overall number of colors?

Comment: I would like the face to have a single color if possible instead of mix of colors, like a cartoon

Comment: I prefer something like this http://akvis.com/en/artwork-tutorial/styles/comics.php where posterizing is set to 70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/07/07/color-quantization-opencv-using-k-means-clustering/

Here is a code that does what you are looking for:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans

n = 32

# read image and convert to gray
img = cv2.imread('./obama.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img = cv2.resize(img, (0,0), fx=.2, fy=.2)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
(h, w) = img.shape[:2]

img =np.reshape(img, (img.shape[0]* img.shape[1], 3))
clt = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=n)
labels = clt.fit_predict(img)
quant = clt.cluster_centers_.astype("uint8")[labels]

quant = np.reshape(quant, (h,w,3))
img = np.reshape(img, (h,w,3))

quant = cv2.cvtColor(quant, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
double = np.hstack([img, quant])
while True:
  cv2.imshow('img', double)
  k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
  if k == 27:
      break
```

You can use this tutorial to apply the color quantization only to boxes containing faces.

https://realpython.com/face-recognition-with-python/

Comment: that's impressive. It will be even better if you could apply it just for the face. +1 !!

Comment: I hope you can solve with my hint.   Let's mark this as solved ;-)